# VS2015 + Cordova + SystemJS + Security Restriction Error: 0x800c001c

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, systemjs

I'm getting an `Unhandled exception 0x800c001c` when I debug my Cordova project for Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows Phone 10. The problem is the `document.write` used in `System.js`.

I understand `winstore-jscompat.js` [link](https://github.com/MsopenTech/winstore-jscompat) is used to resolve this problem, and the `<script src="...` element is in the index HTML. However, it doesn't seem to solve the dynamic content problem with Windows Phone.

[image]

When I look at the dom I can see `winstore-jscompat.js` is dynamically added by `platformOverrides.js` and is located before system.js is called.

[image]

The project code can be download here https://github.com/dbiele/TypeScript-Cordova-SystemJS

Any thoughts?  Not sure if this is a problem with my build machine.  Note: The problem happens when using emulators and physical devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@guybedford was able to answer the question.  Here's his response:

https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/825

> this is the automatic loading SystemJS does when it needs to load the Promise and URL polyfills file at - https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/dist/system-polyfills.js. This is always needed in IE environments including Edge. If you just include that file with a script tag manually before loading SystemJS it won't make that dynamic request anymore.

I updated my platformOverrides.js to:

```
(function () {
// Append the safeHTML polyfill
var scriptElem = document.createElement('script');
scriptElem.setAttribute('src', 'scripts/winstore-jscompat.js');
var scriptElem2 = document.createElement('script');
scriptElem.setAttribute('src', 'scripts/system-polyfills.js');
if (document.body) {
    document.body.appendChild(scriptElem);
    document.body.appendChild(scriptElem2);
} else {
    document.head.appendChild(scriptElem);
    document.head.appendChild(scriptElem2);
}
}());
```