# Unhandled exception with code 0x800c001c. AngularJs, Visual Studio 2015, Cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, windows-10, unhandled-exception, visual-studio-2015

Trying to make a basic app using **AngularJs** with a **Cordova** project on **Visual Studio 2015 Community Ed**.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body ng-app>
    <div>
        10 + 20 = {{ 10 + 20 }}
    </div>

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Upon trying to debug on **Local Machine**, I encounter an **Unhandled exception** with code **0x800c001c**.

[image]

What could be causing this and how to overcome?

Comment: Check out this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32937023/vs2015-cordova-systemjs-security-restriction-error-0x800c001c) it may help out